# Automated Salesforce Login

Tags: python, salesforce-lightning

I have written a little python program that opens Salesforce and updates various fields.

The issue I am having is that to login I have hard coded my login credentials which will mean changing my code every time my password changes. I see it is possible to log in using a consumer key and private key. Will this solve my problem and where do I get my consumer key and private key?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one out:

To get Salesforce KEY and SECRET, you need to go to https://developer.salesforce.com and log in to developer site > Click "Your Name" in upper right corner to expand drop-down menu and then click My Developer Account and log in to your developer account > Again click "Your Name" to expand drop-down menu and then click Setup > Find Build section in left column and click Create in below to expand hidden menu  > find and click Apps in hidden menu (not in right column) > Find Connected Apps section in bottom of right column and then click New > Fill information to get Keys.

Details here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008qsJIAQ